# Must declare the scalar variable @Name

Tags: sql-server

I am new to the forum and can usually find answers to problems by looking at other peoples posts  but I seem to be struggling with this one.

```
SELECT 
    PageId, SubjectLink 
FROM 
    dbo.a_training_page 
WHERE 
    (NOT EXISTS (SELECT PageId, Name 
                 FROM dbo.a_training 
                 WHERE (dbo.a_training_page.PageId = dbo.a_training.PageId) 
                   AND (Name = @Name)))
```

I get an error:

> Must declare the scalar variable @Name

Any help would be gratefully received

Comment: I mean.....you need to declare the variable `@Name`  that you are using in: `AND (Name = @Name)`. Don't know what else to say, the error message is quite clear

Comment: You need to declare the variable.  I'm assuming it's a varchar, so you'll need something like this: `DECLARE @Name VARCHAR (50) = 'Bob'`

Comment: Not sure what is not clear about the error message here.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message very clearly states - you **must declare** any variable (with a leading `@`) in T-SQL before using it - either just in T-SQL code, or as a parameter for a stored procedure or function.

Try this (and lose quite a few of all those unnecessary parenthesis in your `WHERE` clause):

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(100) = 'Brian';

SELECT 
    PageId, SubjectLink 
FROM 
    dbo.a_training_page 
WHERE 
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                FROM dbo.a_training 
                WHERE dbo.a_training_page.PageId = dbo.a_training.PageId
                  AND Name = @Name)
```